# variable degree recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions, closed-form

How to solve the following types of recurrence relation,

$1$. $\;\;a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} ... + a_{n-n}\;\;\;$   where   $\;\;\;a_0 = 1$.

$2$.$\;\;a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} ... + a_{n-\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor} \;\;\;$   where   $\;\;\;a_0 = 1$.

Using small number I can find that, for first question $a_n = 2^{n-1}$
But, in general,

how to apply root method (assuming $a_n = r^n$) here ? Or please mention other methods like generating function that we use to solve recurrence like $\;\;a_n = A.a_{n-1} + B.a_{n-2}$ (degree $2$ in this case)

Thanks !

Comment: In your 2nd question, $a_1$ seems to be undefined, because the final term in the sum would be $a_{n-\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor} = a_1$ which is itself.

Comment: yes, thanks! $a_1$ is needed there. Actually, I randomly took any simple $f(n) \leq n$ just to make the degree variable.  You can safely assume any terminating condition.

Answer (score 1):

Such recurrences are called *full history*. One way to tackle them is to consider $a_{n + 1} - a_n$, most of the sum falls away and you get something manageable.

Another (more general) way is to use generating functions. Say you have:

$\begin{align*}
a_{n + 1}
  &= \sum_{0 \le k \le n} a_k
\end{align*}$

define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, multiply your recurrence by $z^n$ and sum over $n \ge 0$, recognize resulting sums:

$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 1} z^n
  &= \sum_{n \ge 0} z^n \sum_{0 \le k \le n} a_k \\
\frac{A(z) - a_0}{z}
  &= \frac{A(z)}{1 - z}
\end{align*}$

Solve for $A(z)$:

$\begin{align*}
  A(z)
    &= \frac{a_0}{2} + \frac{a_0}{2 (1 - 2 z)} \\
  a_n
    &= [z^n] A(z) \\
    &= \frac{a_0}{2} [n = 0] + \frac{a_0}{2} \cdot 2^n
\end{align*}$

where $[z^n]$ is the "coefficient of $z^n$" operator, and $[n = 0]$ uses Iverson's convention: the bracket is 1 if the condition is true, 0 otherwise.